Print loss after every epoch in YOLOv8
# Build a YOLOv9c model from scratch
model = YOLO('yolov8n.yaml')

# Build a YOLOv9c model from pretrained weight
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

# Display model information (optional)
model.info()

results=model.train(data='data.yaml', epochs=1, imgsz=640, lr0=0.01, batch=32, device=[0, 1], optimizer='SGD', val=False, plots=False)

How to print training class loss after this code? If I write:
print(results), the output is none.
But I want to see all the results such mAP, class loss, and others.

Do you get any logs running this code? Can you add them to this post? By default, yolo prints the following metrics every training epoch: box loss, cls loss, dfl loss, and with val=True you should get in addition box precision, recall, map50 and map50-95. At the end of the training validation metrics are printed too.
